# Dynamic subdomains with a wildcard SSL

Tags: ssl, wildcard, subdomain

i have a project where i need to use dynamic subdomains for each user account over https, lets say:

```
https://username.mydomain.com
```

So as long as i understand i should buy a Wildcard SSL certificate, i was doing that on rapidSSL but before i buy it I read on some forums that it requires a unique IP for each subdomain, that is impossible for me since i will have thousands of thousands of users.

This is true? what should i buy? this will work for me:?

http://www.rapidssl.com/buy-ssl/wildcard-ssl-certificate/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, wildcard SSL certificates are real thing, it will work.  See [on the apache wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts) how to configure it.